# Select text number (numeric text box) in android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, indexing, selection

I'm using Android Studio w/ java and I'm programming a button to reset the values of my numeric text boxes:

```
et1.setText(""); //clear the first numeric text box value
et2.setText(""); //clear the second numeric text box value
tv1.setText(""); //clear the third numeric text box value
?????????????;   //here I need to select et1 (the first numeric textbox)
```

The question is.. how to select the et1 after clear the values ?

Comment: I am beginning programming Android so, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can focus your EditText with `et1.requestFocus()` and then open your keyboard with:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm != null) {
  imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer. I'm gonna try and confirm if it works!

Comment: Hi, et1.requestFocus() worked, and I just try it on my vitual celphone! But i the other code is showing this error: https://imgur.com/a/llwVCD6 .. do you know if I need to add something else?

Comment: Yes, it's an Activity object, could be `this`, `getContext()`, `getActivity()`, a fragment, etc. it's the "context".